# how to copy and paste excel to word with word vba

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I want to insert the Excel file at the seartain BOOkmark in the Word doc without opening Excel, automatically inserted when the Word doc opens.

1.I'm thinking to make a pop up window with a open file dialog bottom firstly. And my code is following:**(but it only work in excel VBA doesn't work in word VBA how should I change the code so that I can do it in word??? )**

```
Sub openfile()
Dim intChoice As Integer
Dim strPath As String
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
If intChoice <> 0 Then
strPath = Application.FileDialog( _
msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
End If
End Sub
```

2. Then I made a copy and paste bottom the code is as follows:**(It also only work when l code it in excel how to change to word vba?)**

   ```
   Sub CopyWorksheetsToWord()
   Dim wdApp As Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document, ws As Worksheet
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.StatusBar = "Creating new document..."
   Set wdApp = New Word.Application
   Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add
   For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

   ws.UsedRange.Copy
   wdDoc.Paragraphs(wdDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range.InsertParagraphAfter
   wdDoc.Paragraphs(wdDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range.Paste
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   wdDoc.Paragraphs(wdDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range.InsertParagraphAfter
   If Not ws.Name = Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Name Then
       With wdDoc.Paragraphs(wdDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range
           .InsertParagraphBefore
           .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
           .InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
       End With
       End If
       Next ws
       Set ws = Nothing
       Application.StatusBar = "Cleaning up..."
       With wdApp.ActiveWindow
       If .View.SplitSpecial = wdPaneNone Then
       .ActivePane.View.Type = wdNormalView
        Else
       .View.Type = wdNormalView
       End If
       End With
       Set wdDoc = Nothing
       wdApp.Visible = True
       Set wdApp = Nothing
       Application.StatusBar = False
       End Sub
   ```

Comment: Your code lacks elementary logic. First, VBA can only run if you have an MS Office document open. Which one is it? You can't open a dialog box to select a document before you have the code running. Next, if you want to open Excel from Word you must first run Word, then create an Excel application. Finally, if you want to select the Excel workbook from a dialog box you can do that from Word. You should bring this much order into your code before you submit it to scrutiny by others. At least, your intention will be/should be clear.

Comment: @Variatus - I think you might be over complicating it.  OP states "When Word opens".  That tells me that they want code in the open event `Document_Open()` that pops up a file selection box, grabs the Excel data with Excel being invisible, and inserts  it into the Word document that is open.  They even gave their code bits and stated that it works in Excel but not Word.

Comment: @Variatus I think what Leila needs here, is just a code snippet, which does the same thing but works in a word file: It can open a given excel file (open but invisible for users) and copy the content from the excel file to the current word file. The code above already does it, but it runs in an excel file and reads the content from the excel file copy it to a given word file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you started.  Place the code below in your Word document in the 'ThisDocument' module.

[image]

---

Add Excel reference to your Word VBA.  In the VBA editor go to Tools and then References.  Check the box next to Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library.

[image]

---

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
    Dim intChoice As Integer
    Dim strPath As String

    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
    intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

    If intChoice <> 0 Then
        strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
    End If

    CopyWorksheetsToWord (strPath)
End Sub


Function CopyWorksheetsToWord(filePath As String)
    Dim exApp As Excel.Application
    Dim exWbk As Excel.Workbook
    Dim exWks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.StatusBar = "Creating new document..."

    Set wdDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set exApp = New Excel.Application
    exApp.Visible = False

    Set exWbk = exApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath)

    For Each exWks In exWbk.Worksheets
        exWks.UsedRange.Copy
        wdDoc.Paragraphs(wdDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range.InsertParagraphAfter
        wdDoc.Paragraphs(wdDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range.Paste
        exApp.CutCopyMode = False
        wdDoc.Paragraphs(wdDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range.InsertParagraphAfter
        If Not exWks.Name = exWbk.Worksheets(exWbk.Worksheets.Count).Name Then
            With wdDoc.Paragraphs(wdDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range
                .InsertParagraphBefore
                .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
                .InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
            End With
        End If
    Next exWks

    Application.StatusBar = "Cleaning up..."

    Set exWks = Nothing
    exWbk.Close
    Set exWbk = Nothing
    Set exApp = Nothing

    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

---

1. Save file as macro-enabled file (.docm)
2. Close word file
3. Open word file and the code will run. First thing you'll see is a file open box to select the Excel file.

*Tested code but there is no error checking.*

---

**Update per comment**

Bookmarks can be located by name using the following syntax: `wdDoc.Bookmarks("Bookmark2").Range`

In this case I inserted a bookmark and labeled it *Bookmark2*

Updated Function Code:

```
Function CopyWorksheetsToWord(filePath As String)
    Dim exApp As Excel.Application
    Dim exWbk As Excel.Workbook
    Dim exWks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim bmRange As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.StatusBar = "Creating new document..."

    Set wdDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set exApp = New Excel.Application
    exApp.Visible = False

    Set exWbk = exApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath)

    For Each exWks In exWbk.Worksheets
        exWks.UsedRange.Copy

        Set bmRange = wdDoc.Bookmarks("Bookmark2").Range
        bmRange.Paste

        exApp.CutCopyMode = False
        wdDoc.Paragraphs(wdDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range.InsertParagraphAfter
        If Not exWks.Name = exWbk.Worksheets(exWbk.Worksheets.Count).Name Then
            With wdDoc.Paragraphs(wdDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range
                .InsertParagraphBefore
                .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
                .InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
            End With
        End If
    Next exWks

    Application.StatusBar = "Cleaning up..."

    Set exWks = Nothing
    exWbk.Close
    Set exWbk = Nothing
    Set exApp = Nothing

    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

Since your looping through sheets you'll probably need to play with formatting and how your stacking each section in the document but this should get you going.

Comment: Thank you for your help! May l ask one more thing ? How to paste the table to a bookmark according to the bookmark 's name?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!